# Send data online from one device to another using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a web application which uses a mobile phone as a controller (an example of this kind of thing: http://chrome.com/supersyncsports/). It isn't something very complicated, I just need to send text which was entered in the phone to the computer. I don't need any database, I just need to send text from one device to another. Is there a way to do this with AJAX and without PHP?
Thanks, 
bhc11

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but it's not simple. You will need to setup a browser-to-browser peer-to-peer connection.

See [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) for a high overview of the technology.

Comment: I see it isn't supported in safari. That's a bit of a problem because I'd like it to work on all devices and browsers. Although Google does require chrome to use the example I gave, so maybe they do use this. If I want it to work on every browser my only choice is a back-end solution (php for me)?

Comment: I believe this is the only "none server" approach. If you need broad support then you will need to use a server to coordinate communications ie. a php app.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some server back-end to process this. You will make your ajax call to the server which reads and determines the location to send the text on to. Since you are using mobile, you will need to either send a push notification to the second user, or you need to have the users polling for new content.

Comment: Although a server backend is one approach, a WebRTC peer-to-peer connection can be used. I assume this is how Google is doing it.